# How to create 3 blocks with 4 elements each in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following PHP code:

```
<div class="search-keywords-div">
    <div class="search-keywords">
        <?php if ( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) ) { $test_input=o t_get_option( 'word'.$i ); echo $i. '. <a href="'.get_option( 'home'). '?s='.$test_input. '">'.$test_input. '</a>'; } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need  3 blocks of 'search-keywords-div' including 4 'search-keywords'
I am wondering how I can do this so effecient as possible. The script uses $i to get the right word from my database.

```
 - Block1 (search-keywords-div): word1(search-keywords),
   word2(search-keywords), word3(search-keywords),
   word4(search-keywords)
 - Block2 (search-keywords-div): word5(search-keywords),
   word6(search-keywords), word7(search-keywords),
   word8(search-keywords)
 - Block3 (search-keywords-div): word9(search-keywords),
   word10(search-keywords), word11(search-keywords), word12
```

I got this as an answer:

```
<div class="search-keywords-body">
    <?php for($i=0 ;$i<3;$i++){ ?>
    <div class="search-keywords-div">
        <?php if($a==0 ){ $c=4 ; } else if($a==1 ){ $c=8 ; } else{ $c=1 2; } ?>
        <?php while($b <=$ c){ ?>
        <div class="search-keywords">
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) ) { $test_input=ot_get_option( 'word'.$b); echo $b. '. <a href="'.get_option( 'home'). '?s='.$test_input. '">'.$test_input. '</a>'; } ?>
        </div>
        <?php $b++;?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php $a++;?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Is this a good way to do realize my goal?

Comment: Are you trying to say you need to use php to generate 3 divs of class "search-keywords-div", each containing 4 divs of class "search-keywords"?

Comment: I need a loop which generates 3 blocks of search-keywords-div that include 4 words (search-keywords). Starting from word1 to word12.